# Restricting SSH access to key-based authentication only

Tags: macos, ssh

So I've successfully authenticated myself with my private key, but now I want to disable passwords all together, so I can only access it with my private key.

I edit `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and I add the following:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
PermitRootLogin no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM no
```

at the bottom of the file. I then restart SSH with:

```
sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist 
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
```

and I try to authenticate with a device that doesn't know my private key at all. I can log in fine just by logging in with my regular user (username@123.123.123.123).

How do I do this? I'm running El Capitan 10.11.1 on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your settings in /etc/ssh/sshd_config, not ssh_config. ssh_config is the global configuration file for the local ssh client software, whereas /etc/ssh/sshd_config is the configuration file for the sshd server.

Comment: I am pretty sure they changed that in a newer version of OS X, because that file does not exist, and when I change the ssh_config I wrote, I get errors when logging in, if I do something "wrong".

Comment: I am running Sierra and here is my /etc/ssh directory:

tatooine-1220:~ mallert$ cd /etc/ssh
tatooine-1220:ssh mallert$ ls ssh*_config
ssh_config sshd_config